# find employees who do not receive commission in sql from emp table

Tags: sql, database

find employees who do not receive commission in sql from emp table

Comment: please provide a database schema, sample data, and a sample of the expected result. Otherwise you will get downvoted rather quickly. Also tag which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 2):

based on your question this should work fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_that_contains_employees_who_do_not_receive_commission
```

Comment: @RohitBit - best you are going to get if you don't explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select name from emp where com is Null;
```

is opretor is used for null value

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ENAME,COMM FROM EMP WHERE COMM IS NULL OR COMM=0;